# Meteor - onCreated collection lookup

Tags: meteor

I'm stumped here. I can't get it to find a collection from the `onCreated` method. If I log the `data.source_id` right before the call and then do the same lookup in the console, it finds it. Is there something special about `onCreated` or something? Am I just doing it wrong?

**client/setup.js**

```
Meteor.subscribe('source_elements');
Meteor.subscribe('internal_elements');
```

**client/submit.js**

```
Router.route('/element/submit', function() {
    this.render('submit', {
        data: {
            source_id: this.params.query.source_id,
        },
    });
});


Template.submit.onCreated(function() {
    var data = Template.instance().data;
    var source_element = SourceElements.findOne({'_id': data.source_id});

    console.log(source_element); // EMPTY!!
});


Template.submit.helpers({
    element: function() {
        var data = Template.instance().data;
        var source_element = SourceElements.findOne({'_id': data.source_id});

        console.log(source_element); // RESULT!!

        return source_element;
    },
});
```

Comment: I see that if I move the call to a helper, it runs a few times (for some reason) and eventually finds it. But the first iteration comes up `undefined`. Perhaps it has something to do with the `return` statements in the `onCreated` method? Or perhaps not using `ReactiveVar`?

Comment: Where are you subscribing to the `SourceElements`?

Comment: Great question. I've added it above. Does what I'm doing ensure that it subscribes first?

Comment: Try using [currentData()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata) inside of your onCreated function instead of instance().

Answer (score 1):

Subscriptions are asynchronous. It looks like you are creating the template before the data has arrived at the client. By the time you execute the `find` in the console, the client has received the data.

Inside your `onCreated` function, you could use [`Tracker.autorun`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) to specify a function that will be rerun when the `SourceElements` collection changes (that's what all template helpers do behind the scenes):

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var element = SourceElements.findOne({'_id': data.source_id});
  console.log(element);
});
```

This function will be called immediately. At this point, `findOne` will probably return `undefined` because the subscription is not ready yet. Once the data has arrived, the function will be called again and you can process the returned elements.